# What is the cause for MySQL: Errorno 150

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone please explain the cause for the following error, 'Can't create table 'Activities' (errno: 150)'

I'm under the understading that the data types and lengths have to be the same, does is have anything to do with the auto increment?

```
Create Table `LinkMemberActivity` (

`LinkID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`MID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,

`AID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`LinkID`),
FOREIGN KEY (`MID`) REFERENCES Members(`MID`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
                                   )
CREATE TABLE `Activities` (

`AID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`Name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,

`MaxCapacity` int(25) DEFAULT NULL,

`StartTime` time DEFAULT NULL,

`EndTime` time DEFAULT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`AID`),
FOREIGN KEY (`AID`) REFERENCES LinkMemberActivity(`AID`)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 );
```

Comment: The referenced column must be primary or unique key,this one LinkMemberActivity(`AID`)

Comment: Your foreign key reference is to a column that is not indexed.

Comment: Would it be possible to explain a little further? @GordonLinoff

Comment: @GrahamWarrender . . . Mihai also answered.  Your foreign key reference should be to `LinkMemberActivity(LinkId)` or `LinkMemberActivity(AID)` should be declared unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to make a primary key column a foreign key dependent field. This is not only unusual but makes no sense in a datamodel, unless it is part of a composite key. Common practice has a column foreign key dependent on another tables primary key. Not sure what reasons you have for the way you designed your datamodel this way, but you can fix this problem by creating a not null autoincrement column named ID and make this column the primary key. Next remove autoincrement from aid.